# Camry 2000 temperature gauge

Tags: toyota, camry

My care shows the temperature gauge was cold when I start the car.  When I move it just kicks off to the middle in less than 1 min. I have seen that when I look at the gauge.

Three weeks ago the car overheated and showed in the temperature gauge, but today I got overheated but the temperature gauge does not show it over heat. It was in the middle. I have seen it does not have enough water, therefor I added some water.

Any thoughts as to what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I would bet the issue is the temperature sending unit (the part on the car which reports the actual temp to the computer/gauge). These sensors work off of resistance. As the temperature gets higher, more resistance is introduced and less voltage gets through. The voltage is read by the computer and then knows the temperature based on a predetermined scale. In your case, the resistace is steady no matter what the temperature and therefor the gauge is reading steady without deference to the actual temperature of the engine.

I'm not sure how the Camry is setup, as in whether it uses one sensor for both the computer and the gauge, or two sensors with one for each. If the car uses one for both, this will also affect how the car runs as the PCM uses the temperature of the engine to determine how much fuel is needed for optimal running.

I would give you more advice on fixing the issue and how to test things, but you didn't provide enough data about the car itself.